# How to redirect to homepage if end user refreshes or hit enter in the address bar?

Tags: angular, apache, https, apache2

I have a angular2+ project which is hosted on apache2 .

Currently, when I refresh the page or hit enter ,the url remains same but it gives the `404 error`.

I am looking for a solution to redirect to homepage if the user presses enter in the address bar or refreshes the page .

Later on the case may vary i.e if the session is present the user should remain on the same page from which he/she presses enter or reload the page  .

Shall I need to change any entry in the Apache2 config. or do I need to it in the angular itself .

```
Programming Language  : Angular2+
Server : Apache2
Connection : https (SSL enabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user refreshs the page, your app will be restarted.

So a simple solution would be to see at initialization (in your `app.component.ts` for example) what the route is. For this you can use the service `private route:ActivatedRoute`.

If the route is not what you are expected, you can `navigate` with the router to your home.